# Failed to Connect To Tango - Qianru

Tags: android, google-project-tango

Whenever I try to launch Tango apps on my Dev Kit, I get the error

> Failed to connect to Tango

Or

> System unavailable, please restart the App or the System

I did a factory reset when I got the device, and was prompted to do an OTA update.  Build Number KOT49H.160624

Tango Core has updated through the Play Store - Qianru v1.37:2016.06.13

After a few seconds of the "Hold Tight" message, I'm either presented with an error - or the device stays on "Hold Tight".

I've rebooted the device, updated all apps via play.

[image]

[image]

Occurs on Unity apps as well as Android SDK apps.

The Tango Debug Overlay doesn't show any information

[image]

At a loss with what to do here.  How do I get Tango to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a physical defect with the unit. I cracked it open and discovered that one of the contacts had come loose.

[image]

I gently pushed the silver tab in the centre back in, everything works fine now.

Comment: May I ask you how did you open it?
Is the "Project Tango Tablet Development Kit"?

Comment: Using a spludger, my fingernails, and brute force!